# Monocular Total Capture usage error : import numpy as np ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, import, openpose

I'm trying to use this repo :

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture

I've completed the installation part and I started to use it. This is what I should do :

> In ${ROOT}, run "bash run_pipeline.sh ${seqName}"; if the subject in the video shows only upper body, run "bash run_pipeline.sh ${seqName}
>   -f".

So,I created a folder and I named it "example_dance" and inside of it I have copied the file named "example_dance.mp4",the same file used as an example and then I ran :

```
mario@ziom-Z87-HD3:/home/ziom/Scrivania/MonocularTotalCapture# bash run_pipeline.sh example_dance

ls: can't log into '/home/ziom/Scrivania/MonocularTotalCapture/data/example_dance/openpose_result/*': File o directory not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "POF/collect_openpose.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy
```

how to fix it ? I tried some experiments,such as :

```
mario@ziom-Z87-HD3:/home/ziom/Scrivania/MonocularTotalCapture# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> exit()
```

and :

```
pip install numpy
pip2 install numpy 
pip3 install numpy
apt-get install python-numpy
```

I have also tried get the source of the numpy and then I did :

```
python setup.py install
```

,numpy has been installed correctly,but the error is still there.

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: with conda ? no

Comment: I meant in general, regardless of the particular tool. I would recommend doing so, it helps eliminate these kinds of issues.

Comment: I'm trying without success.

Comment: Trying what, and in what way isn’t it working?

Comment: check this video : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bnn_tshQfdIaxv3PnghhE-bC8pZJ7vt6

Comment: What is that, what am I looking at?

Comment: read the usage part of this project : https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture ; I'm trying to use it,after having configured everything. Point 1 : Suppose the video to be tested is named "${seqName}.mp4". Place it in "${ROOT}/${seqName}/${seqName}.mp4" and point 3 : In ${ROOT}, run "bash run_pipeline.sh ${seqName}". this is what I'm trying to do.