# Opencv 2.4.13 requires python 2.7,but the Monocular Total Capture repo requires python 3.5

Tags: python, linux, opencv, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm trying to use this repo :

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture

It requires "OpenCV 2.4.13 (compiled from source with CUDA 9.0, CUDNN 7.0)",so I'm trying to install it with conda. The default python installation on my systen is :

```
(base) root@ziom-Z87-HD3:/home/ziom# python
Python 2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 24 2019, 21:51:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
```

but the repo requires python 3.5,for this reason I switched to it with this command :

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
```

and it seems that it worked.

```
(base) root@ziom-Z87-HD3:/home/ziom# python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

now,it requires to install python 3.5 and OpenCV 2.4.13,so I give this command :

```
conda create -n ziomario pip python=3.5
conda activate ziomario
```

at this point I should install OpenCV 2.4.13 and I give this command :

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=2.4.13
```

but it does not work,because this :

```
(ziomario) root@ziom-Z87-HD3:/home/ziom# conda install -c conda-forge opencv=2.4.13
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining @/linux-64::__glibc==2.23=0:  25%|██▌       | 1/4 [00:00<00:00, 6026.3Examining python=3.5:  50%|█████     | 2/4 [00:00<00:00, 7351.98it/s]           Examining conflict for python opencv:  25%|██▌       | 1/4 [00:00<00:00, 10979.8                                                                                failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - opencv=2.4.13 -> python=2.7

Your python: python=3.5

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==9.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 9.0
```

Opencv=2.4.13 requires python=2.7,but the repo requires python 3.5. I don't know what to do.

Comment: _but the repo requires python 3.5,for this reason I switched to it with this command_ What is the point of doing that? Won't you be running Python from an environment anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange because the repo explicitly says that it should use what you are trying to use. My guess is that someone made a mistake on the dependency list. Try upgrading Opencv first then contact the repo maintainers since they wrote the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you may want to use "pyenv"

I found that website which is really useful: https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

I will write a summary of the steps assuming you're using an Ubuntu or Debian system.

First you Download dependencies if you haven't done it:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl
```

Then you use pyenv-installer:

```sh
$ curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

This will install pyenv along with a few plugins that are useful:

1. pyenv: The actual pyenv application
2. pyenv-virtualenv: Plugin for pyenv and virtual environments
3. pyenv-update: Plugin for updating pyenv
4. pyenv-doctor: Plugin to verify that pyenv and build dependencies are installed
5. pyenv-which-ext: Plugin to automatically lookup system commands

At the end of the run, you should see something like this:

```
WARNING: seems you still have not added 'pyenv' to the load path.

# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bashrc:

export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

The output will be based on your shell. But you should follow the instructions to add pyenv to your path and to initialize pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv auto completion. Once you’ve done this, you need to reload your shell:
```

```
$ exec "$SHELL" # Or just restart your terminal
```

Then, you can install the version of python with that command:

```sh
$ pyenv install -v 3.5
```

And more... (go to website)

Comment: I did : conda create -n ziomario pip python=2.7 ; conda activate ziomario ; conda install -c conda-forge opencv=2.4.13. I've got no errors,but Im not sure if it is correct because I get the same error as before : ImportError: No module named 'numpy'. Maybe this is not the solution for this error. Go here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622518/monocular-total-capture-usage-error-import-numpy-as-np-importerror-no-module